# Can a Trane TWE042C150B1 be connected to a honeywell t9 smart thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, furnace

I went to replace my old honeywell thermostat with an updated T9, but the new thermostat wouldn't even start up. Digging in, the 'C' connection was on the 'B' connection at the Trane. There is no 'C' there.
Is my Trane to old to work with newer thermostats?
Pics of the old thermostat and Trane are attached.
[image: Old Thermostat]
[image: Trane connections]

Comment: You should measure 24 VAC between the R and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "B" is "C" for you

On older Trane systems, like yours, they use "B" as the designation for what's really their C terminal, so connect that wire to C on your thermostat, and the wire from O to O/B, then you should be good to go.

Comment: Hmm. I had done that with no love. They tell me I should be getting 24v AC between R and C.
I seem to be getting 24V dc that way, though, so I was thinking my furnace is too old.
Maybe they sent me a bad unit.

Comment: @BrianAndrus what model is your furnace? That's weird that you'd be getting DC from R to B...

Comment: The model is in the title.
It looks like the fuse blew, so I am waiting for a replacement. That may have been what happened that made it seem to not work. Fingers crossed. Lame that they have the fuse glued to the cap, so you have to buy the 'special' replacement